# Select *, count(*) in one Query

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a DB with a few columns and I'm trying to populate a html table with it. 
Everything's going fine but I've encountered the following problem:

Since I'm filling filtered Results into different Columns, I came up with a SQL Query that needs both Select * and count(*)?

```
$query = "SELECT *, COUNT(example_A) AS total_example_A FROM test WHERE example_A = 'certain_result' AND date(start_date) = '$current_date_proof' ORDER BY start_date ASC";
```

It does work, but I'm only getting the first result. I guess I cannot combine Select with Count?

Comment: Try to understand what select * does and what count(*) does.
Count(*) gives you result of a set of group and is scalar. Hence returns only single row

Comment: `COUNT` is an aggregator function, and therefore requires the use of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GunnrryyTo be precise, `Count` or any aggregation function (`Avg`, `Sum`, ...) returns one row per group.

Comment: Documentation states: "_If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows_". So GROUP BY is not required. Just to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a correlated sub-query,  Count is an aggregation function ( so it aggregates or combines all the data ):

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        t1.*,
        ( SELECT COUNT(t0.id) FROM test AS t0 WHERE t0.id = t1.id ) AS total_example_A
    FROM
        test AS t1
    WHERE
            t1.example_A = 'certain_result'
        AND
            date(t1.start_date) = '$current_date_proof'
    ORDER BY t1.start_date ASC
";
```

This assumes that your table `test` has a primary key named `id`.  One other thing is I would count on the primary key  if its not (example_A)  `COUNT(t0.id)`

In my world a database either have a `Auto Increment Int` as the primary key or they have a compound primary key consisting of 2 or more foreign keys which are themselves `Auto Increment Int` fields. It's vital ( IMO ) to always have a surrogate key in you table.  That is a key that has no direct relationship to the data itself.  But, that is just me...

You could just count the return within your application, but barring that the correlated sub-query should give you the best/goodest performance. Certainly much better then a separate database call.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. And yes I have an ID with auto increment – didn't think of using that!

Comment: It does work – but the count result seems to be wrong ( = 1), it should be 2 in my example.

Comment: There is no way for me to tell without the data you have, have you tried running the query without the sub-query, to see what it pulls.

Comment: It works without the subquery. I just seem to be unable to wrap my head around the "count the filtered results" thing.

When I edit the subquery and change your "WHERE" statement to "WHERE t0.example_A = 'certain result' - It counts to 3. So one too much. It seems we're pretty close here..

Comment: Did you try the subquery with the where clause from the outer query?  `"SELECT COUNT(example_A) AS total_example_A FROM test WHERE example_A = 'certain_result' AND date(start_date) = '$current_date_proof' ORDER BY start_date ASC"`

Comment: see you have to check each part, if they are correct separately then you can try putting the same where clause in the sub-query, it wont be correlated but it should work

Comment: thank you! Seems to have worked by adding the complete WHERE statement from the main query! Thank you so much!